# error 0xc0000005 when I run TOR

Tags: error, startup

Macbook Pro with a full Microsoft Windows 7 64bits installed but everytime I try to run TOR, it-s unable to go somewhere, and instead I have this bizarre warning: 
Unable to run TOR (0xc0000005), and I can't get it past this screeen. And I am also unable to uninstall it. It says the installer stopped working. What could that be? I am fearing it's a harware issue

Comment: This is likely your anti-virus, firewall, trusteer rapport, or similar software that is trying to spy on tor browser and accidentally breaking it.

Answer (score 0):

So after a little research, I found out that this may be an Windows patch problem.
I'm not sure if this could help, but still try.

1. Press Win+R, type `cmd.exe`.
2. Type this: wusa.exe /uninstall /kb:2859537

This uninstalls the patch that may cause you this trouble.